# ObjectDataSource do not call SelectCountMethod

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, objectdatasource

I am using SelectCountMethod to count rows returned but it is not being called for new classes i added .

Below is my code for UI.

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjDS1" runat="server" EnablePaging="false"    TypeName="SomeBusinesslogicclass"
                       SelectCountMethod="GetCallCount" SelectMethod="sp_gettotalcallsummary2_ivr"   OnSelecting="objDS_Selecting1"
                        OnSelected="objDS_Selected1">
```

Business Logic

```
public int GetCallCount(string Provider , string FromCallDate , string ToCallDate)
    {

        CallSummaryRepository rep = new CallSummaryRepository();
        return rep.GetCallCount(Provider,FromCallDate,ToCallDate);
    }
```

Data Access Layer

```
  public int GetCallCount(string Provider , string FromCallDate , string ToCallDate)
    {
        int count = 0;
        using (IVREntities context = new IVREntities())
        {
            var query = (from ap in context.sp_gettotalcallsummary2(Provider, FromCallDate, ToCallDate)

                         select ap

                        );


            count = query.Count();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I have put breakpoints and tried to debug the code but it never gets into the GetCallCount function. I know the question is already asked few times but those answers do not solve my problem

Comment: Do the parameters of your `SelectCountMethod` match the parameters of your `SelectMethod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem . I had set the paging property to false .